# How can a jar with specific deps be created, after using maven-dependency-plugin to select the wanted deps?

Tags: maven

My goal is to create a jar with specific dependencies from my dependency list in the pom. I'm using maven-dependency-plugin like so:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                <excludes>META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/uber-deps/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.some.blaClass</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and an assembly.xml file holding:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>plugin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <includes>
                <include>
                    ${project.build.directory}/uber-deps/
                </include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*:sources</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

After `mvn clean install` all relevant dependencies appear in target/uber-deps as I would expect. **My problem** is with the next plugin under `<plugins>` - maven-assembly-plugin. Seems to me as if it doesn't take uber-deps in.

I know this only by trying to unpack the jar using `jar xf` to see if the deps in uber-deps were packed in the jar created after `mvn clean install`.

What should be changed?

Comment: Why not using maven-assembly-plugin or maven-shade-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I can't use maven-shade-plugin, trying to use usemaven-assembly-plugin. The include I wrote is inside the assembly plugin part.

Comment: I think that for your use case you need to provide assembly plugin with assembly file (xml). Not sure if you can do it otherwise. it would help if you post here the full definition of your `maven-assembly-plugin`

Comment: I have an assembly file, will edit the original message with both assembly file and maven-assembly-plugin part. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: also @Yaelz - note that assembly plugin creates *another* jar in target folder, so you might be looking at the wrong jar

Comment: I'm looking at both sources.jar and .jar

Comment: The given transformer in the code snippet you have given in your question is from maven-shade-plugin ...and not from maven-assembly-plugin....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
The jar you are building as part of the `assembly-plugin` will be called (by default) `./target/<artifactId>-plugin.jar`

Note that the `plugin` part is what you've put under `id` in your assembly xml file.

---

2)
Since you already unpack the dependencies to a folder, you should use `fileSets` rather then `dependencySets`:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>
                    ${project.build.directory}/uber-deps/
                </include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</fileSets>
```

---

3)
BTW if you want the outputs of your own project in that jar you should add another `fileSet`:

```
<fileSet>
    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>
            ${project.build.outputDirectory}
        </include>
    </includes>
</fileSet>
```

---

4) Also just noted that your assembly plugin definition is not stating the location of your assembly xml file and that you try to define mainClass using `shade-plugin` configuration. This is how it should look in assembly plugin (assuming that your assembly file is located under `src/assembly/plugin.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/plugin.xml</descriptor>
                 </descriptors>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.some.blaClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```